# convert.exe (ImageMagick) showing blank after converting large svg to png/pdf

Tags: svg, imagemagick, im4java

While converting a large svg to pdf I am getting blank output after converting and the following error.

```
Error in im4java org.im4java.core.commandexception return code:3
```

I am executing the following:

```
convert s.svg s.pdf
```

Environment details:

ImageMagick 6.9.2-0 Q16 x86

Windows 7 x86

Comment: A few suggestions... show us the minimal svg that doesn't work, show us the `convert` command you are using, tells us your `ImageMagick` version and platform.

Comment: Please don't embed all the information that should be in your question all over the place in comments - it makes it hard to read :-) Instead, click `edit` underneath your question and update your question with all the details so people can find them easily - and, hopefully, assist you.

Comment: tried to improve the readability and added the info from the comments